# Why does fwrite (with struct) writes unknown symbols?

Tags: c, fwrite

I want to write a struct to the txt file with fwrite function. When I run my program I see a lot of undefined symbols in the txt file. Why does it happen and how can I fix it?
My code:

```
FILE *file = NULL;

file = fopen(TASK1_2_FILENAME, "wb");

if (!file) {
    printf("FATAL: File does not exist, exiting.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

Products product;
strcpy(product.date, "00:00:0000");
product.code = 12345;
product.quantity = 10;
product.price = 10.5;

fwrite(&product, sizeof(Products), 1, file);

fclose(file);
```

And the structure in headers file:

```
typedef struct Product {
    char date[11];
    int code;
    int quantity;
    float price;
} Products;
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Please pick one language. What else did you expect to appear in the file?

Comment: It is because you are writing binary data to a text file. You need to examine a memory dump instead.

Comment: What do you expect to see? Your text editor is trying to interpret the bytes of the numbers as characters.

Comment: See [binary files](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/B/binary_file.html)... You are supposed to **have those *undefined symbols*... and those are actually bytes which you have opened using a text editor... use a [hex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor) instead...**

Comment: Oh, so that is correct? Cause I am not familiar with binary files. If that is fine - let me know.

Comment: It does the same thing for any `int` and any `float`.  Being inside a `struct` isn't affecting the behavior at all.

Comment: @WeatherVane: no, it's the other way around. It is because [you] are opening a binary file as if it's a text file.

Comment: @usr2564301 yes, I saw "I want to write a struct to the txt file" and didn't notice the `"wb"`.

Comment: If you want to read/write a text file then you need to print and scan your values as text. If you want a binary file, you can read/write the raw data without needing to do any special handling—but you won't be able to easily look at it using a text editor.

Comment: Why not fread the file back into a second struct  Product and print or compare that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write binary data and expect it to be text. The behavior you're seeing is normal, expected, and correct.

As an example, think of the number `30000`.  This will easily fit inside a two-byte `short int`. However, in text format you have at least five bytes. If you `fwrite()` two bytes to external storage, it will be two bytes containing the numerical value of those bytes, not a text representation of each digit.

In the example of `30000` the binary representation is `01110101 00110000`. This is reversed in Intel machines because they are [little-endian](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian). That means those two bytes in your file are probably decimal 48 and 118. If you view those as characters on a PC that used ASCII natively, they should show up as `0` and `v`, respectively.